# re.sub erroring with "Expected string or bytes-like object"

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nltk

I have read multiple posts regarding this error, but I still can't figure it out. When I try to loop through my function:

```py
def fix_Plan(location):
    letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]",  # Search for all non-letters
                          " ",          # Replace all non-letters with spaces
                          location)     # Column and row to search    

    words = letters_only.lower().split()
    stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))
    meaningful_words = [w for w in words if not w in stops]
    return (" ".join(meaningful_words))

col_Plan = fix_Plan(train["Plan"][0])
num_responses = train["Plan"].size
clean_Plan_responses = []

for i in range(0,num_responses):
    clean_Plan_responses.append(fix_Plan(train["Plan"][i]))
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxxx/PycharmProjects/tronc/tronc2.py", line 48, in <module>
    clean_Plan_responses.append(fix_Plan(train["Plan"][i]))
  File "C:/Users/xxxxx/PycharmProjects/tronc/tronc2.py", line 22, in fix_Plan
    location)  # Column and row to search
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: If you are getting an error, *always post the full error including the stack trace*.

Comment: Please `print(train["Plan"][i])` and see what it is. Do it before the call to `fix_Plan()` in the for loop. I don't think `train["Plan"][i]` is what you expected to be.

Comment: can you add try: except in fix_Plan also if location:

Comment: It is a string from an excel document formatted like this:
Video editing: Further develop video production skills using tools such as Wochit, Videolicious and iMovie.

Develop a production plan specific to sports that matches effort to potential audience/impact.

Expand HTML/CSS skills and identify one to two projects in Sports that could benefit from being presented in an HTML story then implement.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's a string? Try printing `type(train['Plan'][i])`

Comment: C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py 

looks like it is not string and re is complaining

Comment: Ok, so apparently some of them are floats. How can I make them strings?

Comment: use the built-in `str` function?

Comment: Well the majority of the types are strings, but there are a few that are floats.

Comment: str(somestring)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

As you stated in the comments, some of the values appeared to be floats, not strings. You will need to change it to strings before passing it to `re.sub`. The simplest way is to change `location` to `str(location)` when using `re.sub`. It wouldn't hurt to do it anyways even if it's already a `str`.

```
letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]",  # Search for all non-letters
                          " ",          # Replace all non-letters with spaces
                          str(location))
```

Comment: I wrote two notebooks on in Jupyter and one in Kaggle Kernels. Jupyter one works fine and produces correct output. Kaggle Notebook gives me an error and I followed your solution and the error was removed but now sentiment prediction result it wrong.

Answer (score 28):

The simplest solution is to apply **Python** `str` function to the column you are trying to loop through.

If you are using `pandas`, this can be implemented as:

```
dataframe['column_name']=dataframe['column_name'].apply(str)
```

Comment: I would suggest fill nan values with '' 
`dataframe['column_name'] = dataframe['column_name'].fillna('').apply(str)` because in most use cases people will not want nan to be literal 'nan'

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot! Wish I had read this 1.5h ago. The following converted the column in the DF but also replaced the content (which I do not want!) ```df['col'] = repr(df['col'])```  ```df['col'] = str(df['col'])```   ```df['col'] = df.col.astype('str')```  This threw an encoding error ```df['col'] = df.col.astype('|S')```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. And it's very interesting that every time I did something, the problem was not solved until I realized that there are two special characters in the string.

For example, for me, the text has two characters:

`&lrm;` <sub>([Left-to-Right Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark))</sub> and  `&zwnj;` <sub>([Zero-width non-joiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner))</sub>

The solution for me was to delete these two characters and the problem was solved.

```py
import re
mystring = "&lrm;Some Time W&zwnj;e"
mystring  = re.sub(r"&lrm;", "", mystring)
mystring  = re.sub(r"&zwnj;", "", mystring)
```

I hope this has helped someone who has a problem like me.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose better would be to use re.match() function. here is an example which may help you.

```
import re
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
nltk.download('punkt')
sentences = word_tokenize("I love to learn NLP \n 'a :(")
#for i in range(len(sentences)):
sentences = [word.lower() for word in sentences if re.match('^[a-zA-Z]+', word)]  
sentences
```

Comment: Why is it better to use the re.match() function?

Answer (score 0):

from my experience in Python, this is caused by a None value in the second argument used in the function **re.findall()**.

```
import re
x = re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]", None)
```

One reproduce the error with this code sample.

To avoid this error message, one can filter the null values or add a condition to put them out of the processing

Comment: Please make sure to abstract to the generic. Sure: None could be a problem, but so could be a float or int. Like the error says: Anything that isn't a string or a byte-like object causes the error. If you limit it to a specific error case it may not be helpful

Answer (score 0):

### Use `str.replace` instead

This is about 7 years too late for OP but if you got here because you got a similar error by using `re.sub` on a pandas column, consider using `str.replace` built into pandas instead. The reason is that the most common reason this error pops up is when a pandas column contains (unexpected) NaN values in it which `re.sub` cannot handle whereas `str.replace` handles it under the hood for us.

Example:

```py
train = pd.DataFrame({'Plan': ["th1s", '1s', 'N01ce', 'and', float('nan')]})

[re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", x) for x in train['Plan']]      # <--- TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
train['Plan'].str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z]", " ", regex=True)  # <--- OK
```

---

Now for OP, their `fix_Plan` function does more than just replacing strings; however, we can still do all of that in a vectorized way as follows (more or less replace `re` functions by its pandas counterparts).

```py
stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))
stop_words = '|'.join(fr"\b{w}\b" for w in stops)  # pattern to catch stop words
clean_Plan_responses = (
    train['Plan']
    .str.replace("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", regex=True)     # replace all non-letters with spaces
    .str.lower()                                   # convert to lower case
    .str.replace(stop_words, "", regex=True)       # remove all stop words
    .str.split().str.join(" ")                     # remove extraneous space characters
)
```