# Replacing words in a file with re

Tags: python

I have a function which iterates over a text file, matches words to keys in a dictionary, and changes these words to the keys values:

```
def replace_operators(text):
    operators = {'order': '"order"'}
    f = open(text, 'r').read()

    for k, v in operators.items():
        cleaned = re.sub(r"\b%s\b" % k, v, f)
        f = open(text, 'w')
        f.truncate(0)
        f.close()
        text_file = open(text, 'w')
        text_file.write(cleaned)
        text_file.close()
```

This works fine, however when I add another key to the dictionary, I receive:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I've tried the solution of replacing f with str(f) in the cleaned line (suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727583/expected-string-or-bytes-like-object) answer), however this only writes the following line to my outfile:

> <_io.TextIOWrapper "name"='path/of/outfile' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>

Does anyone know how I can add more keys without getting this kind of error?

Comment: after your first time through the `for k, v in ...` loop, `f` is the closed file object, not the result of the initial read.

Comment: also if you open file in write mode continually, you will clear all the previously stored content of file on each iteration

Comment: Both your points make a lot of sense, thankyou. Is there a solution that you would suggest?

Comment: one place to start is to change `'w'` to `'a'` which means append, and then move your f.close() and text_file.close() outside of your for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a loop for this, or to replace & write the file several times. A very efficient approach is:

- open & read the file
- use regex *replacement function* with a lambda, trying to match the words of the text with the dictionary, returning the same word if not found
- open & write the file (or a new file)

like this:

```
import re

text = "input.txt"

operators = {'order': '"order"', 'matter':'"matter"'}
with open(text, 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()

cleaned = re.sub(r"\b(\w+)\b",lambda m : operators.get(m.group(1),m.group(1)),contents)

with open("new_"+text, 'w') as f:
    f.write(cleaned)
```

This little-known feature is very powerful. It allows to pass a *function* as a replacement (not a string). This function takes the match as input, and returns the string that must replace the match as output. My function is an anonymous function (lambda):

```
lambda m : operators.get(m.group(1),m.group(1))
```

so if the matched word is in the dictionary, it returns & replaces by the value, else it returns the original word.

All that without a loop  & `O(1)` word lookup, so super fast even if you have a *lot* of items in your dictionary (as opposed to linear nth replace approach, or building list of keywords with `"|".join()`, which starts to crawl when you have 1000+ items to search/replace)

Comment: Very nice, worked perfectly and runs very quickly, thankyou.