# Python3, when UserString does not behave as a string?

Tags: python, string

In Python3 I use a `UserString` to expand the functionality of built-in strings. Usually `UserString`s behave just like `str`s, but with `re` I run into an unexpected `TypeError`:

```
bpython version 0.17.1 on top of Python 3.6.9 /usr/bin/python3

import re
from collections import UserString

s = UserString('foo')
re_repetitions = re.compile(r"(/)\1{1,}", re.DOTALL)
re_repetitions.sub(r"\1", s)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    re_repetitions.sub(r"\1", s)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

-- why is it so? Usually `UserString` "quacks" like a string, but `re` does not treat it as such? Where else a `UserString` does not behave like a `str`?

Comment: `UserString` has `.data` property, so you can write `re_repetitions.sub(r"\1", s.data)`

Comment: I disagree with downvoting this question. I could not find the other one and stackoverflow did not suggest it among similar questions. I doubt that somebody else who needs to expand some behaviour of `str` and uses `UserString` will be able to find that question because it deals with Pandas and nltk. Moreover, my use-case is much more to the point than the other one.

Comment: Moreover! [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43727749/1420489) to the other question starts with "As you stated in the comments, some of the values appeared to be floats, not strings..." -- it is a trivial situation that does not correspond clearly to the tricky case of `UserString`. **That is exactly why I asked this question: `UserString` "quacks" like a string -- therefore why does not `re` treat it as such?** The other question and the answer will most likely confuse another person in my situation.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew I edited the question to stress the main point of the issue: I do not run `re` on a `float` as in the linked question, the error message `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` does not say explicitly that it requires a `str` object, the documentation on [`UserString`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserString) states "UserString(seq) Class that simulates a string object", which is also confusing. I think my question presents the issue better and is more useful to `UserString` user than the linked q. Would you consider re-opening?

Comment: I am not sure if the comment reference worked with a hyphen in it. Just to be sure, let me add another @Wiktor reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would like to add some information actually about `UserString` class.

Python's built-in types, like `str`, are actually not real Python classes, but C constructions (assuming the standard Python implementation, CPython). It helps with speed and probably with Python-C interoperability, but the behaviour of built-ins can be different from usual user's classes. There are cases when this implementation detail matters.

This is an example of such situation. Probably, regexp engine behind `re` is written in C and works with C strings. `UserString` ["simulates a string object"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserString) but it is not one.

It seems that all C routines do not work with `UserString`. For example, you cannot run `importlib`, `subprocess`, or `os.path` on this class.
There was [an enhancement proposition](https://bugs.python.org/issue232493) about it in 2001. But a fix was not implemented, because there is no easy way to do it.

Therefore, there is no standard way to fix it. You need to use some work-around: either `.data` as in chepner's answer, or as in the linked question do `str(UserString('foo'))`.

In addition, the error message

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

actually means that it needs a `str` object. By default "string" means `str` in Python. Which can be confusing in case of "string-like" objects etc.

---

Finally, in my real use case I had to use a string-like class `MyString` which could be extended with new methods in future.
For the time being I just used a `MyString = str` and thought that it will be easily extensible in the future when the need comes.

The need came, I defined `class MyString(UserString)` and my tests told me that they need a string.
Now, in somewhat awkward and non-Pythonic way, half of my code treats `MyString` as a string and another half does `MyString('foo').data`. And to make things worse this `MyString` class is a part of the interface of one of the modules.
So a user must know the implementation details behind the interface of the module...

In my case it seems that I can code around this issue.
But that requires some re-writing of the whole module.
So probably the feature implemented with `UserString` is not worth the effort right now.

Comment: it would be a good manner if the person who voted down mentioned the reason

Answer (score 2):

An instance of [`UserString`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L1131) isn't an instance of `str`, but it does *contain* a `str`:

```
re_repetitions.sub(r"\1", s.data)
```

Comment: For others who need to use `UserString`, notice that it does not behave as a `str` in a number of other important situations: `import` does not handle it, and you cannot run a `subprocess` with a `UserString` command name.

Comment: heh, in 2001 there actually was an enhancement proposition about this situation: [UserString can not be used as string in calls to C routines](https://bugs.python.org/issue232493) -- the resolution would be "a major project" and it was postponed till Python 3000.