# Python `UserString` seems problematic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-collections

I need to use `UserString` to create my own `str` class, but its implementation seems problematic.

For example, in the class definition, it reads:

```
    def __eq__(self, string):
        if isinstance(string, UserString):
            return self.data == string.data
        return self.data == string
```

But since an empty list (`[]`) is actually an instance of `UserString`:

```
isinstance([], UserString) == True
```

Now this code doesn't work:

```
s = UserString("")
if s in [None, [], {}, ()]:
    # do whatever
```

because `in` operator will use `UserString`'s `__eq__` to check membership but `[]` does not have `.data` attribute. This issue doesn't exist in the built-in `str` class.
I know this is a trivial, non-realistic example, but anyone encountered this problem before using `UserString` and what is the best way to circumvent this (maybe method override in my own subclass)? Any other caveats?

Note: I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756050/python3-when-userstring-does-not-behave-as-a-string) SO thread, but I don't think my question is a duplicate of it.

It seems like no one can reproduce `isinstance([], UserString) == True`. But this is a screenshot from my PyCharm IDE:
[image: This is a screenshot from my PyCharm IDE]

Comment: I just ran `isinstance([], collections.UserString)` and got `False`.

Comment: @0x5453 Strange! It returns `True` in my PyCharm IDE running Python 3.8. What are you using?

Comment: Can not reproduce `isinstance([], UserString) == True`

Comment: @wim I am not sure what happened. Attached a screenshot just so that no one thinks that I am just being crazy.

Comment: Also have `isinstance([], UserString) == False`. Also checked using Pycham's Python Console.

Comment: Hmm, can not reproduce even on 3.8.2 but I am on Linux.  What is `repr(UserString)` ?

Comment: @wim 
>>>repr(UserString)
"<class 'collections.UserString'>"

Comment: Super weird.  Can you show us `UserString.__mro__`?

Comment: @wim Sure: 
(<class 'collections.UserString'>, <class 'collections.abc.Sequence'>, <class 'collections.abc.Reversible'>, <class 'collections.abc.Collection'>, <class 'collections.abc.Sized'>, <class 'collections.abc.Iterable'>, <class 'collections.abc.Container'>, <class 'object'>)

Comment: All looks normal.  Just to confirm, the error message you're seeing is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data'` ?

Comment: @wim That's right, for that trivial example I showed, and after I looked into it, I thought it had to be `__eq__` considering `[]` as an instance of `UserString`. And then apparently my (and only my) Python console confirmed my theory, LOL. If Python is not the issue, my only guess would be Clang...but that's a wild guess?

Comment: How Python was installed? Did you compile this Python interpreter yourself?

Comment: You could try to run that with different Python's version, if you have any others.

Comment: @wim I just double checked from my Terminal console instead of PyCharm, it did return `False`. I think the issue is with PyCharm's Python Console somehow "altered" something.

Comment: It works on my Pycharm properly. Which version of this IDE you have?

Comment: @AdamTokarski I am using Professional 2020.3.1.

Comment: Did you check how it behaves with any other `isinstance` calls? Using another types or objects?

Comment: @AdamTokarski I did try `isinstance([], str)` and got `False`, and that's why I thought `UserString` might be the issue. `isinstance({}, UserString)` returns `True`, while `isinstance((), UserString)` returns `False`.

Comment: Clutching at straws here but check if `import builtins; builtins.isinstance is isinstance`.  The pydevconsole.py is pretty disgusting, I wouldn't put it past them to monkeypatch that.

Comment: Thanks @wim `builtins.isinstance is isinstance` returns `True` but at this point, only I can figure out what in the world happened to *my* PyCharm. Thanks again.