# Class decoration causes trouble to isinstance(), but how (and why)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a follow-up question (related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66018017/python-userstring-seems-problematic) I asked) but it is complicated enough that I think it is better to start a new question.

Previously, I discovered that for whatever reason, I have:

```
isinstance([], UserString) == True
```

But this is clearly not right. After a bunch of digging, I think my other code is causing this issue but I don't know how it is possible.

This is the minimal code that can reproduce the problematic result above:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def func_decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            res = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return res
        return wrapper

    def class_decorator(cls):
        # set of callable function names already been decorated/inspected
        handled_funcs = {'__new__', '__init__', '__del__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__class__'}
        for key in cls.__dict__:
            # Only callable functions are decorated
            value = getattr(cls, key)
            if not callable(value):
                continue
            handled_funcs.add(key)
            setattr(cls, key, func_decorator(value))
        # Handle the remaining base classes (skip Mixin)
        for base in cls.__mro__[2:]:
            for key in base.__dict__:
                value = getattr(base, key)
                if not callable(value) or key in handled_funcs:
                    continue
                handled_funcs.add(key)
                setattr(cls, key, func_decorator(value))
        return cls

    class Mixin():
        def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
            super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
            class_decorator(cls)

    class MyUserString(Mixin, UserString):
        def __init__(self, seq, *, synthesized=False):
            super().__init__(synthesized, seq)

    print(isinstance([], UserString)) # this will print True
```

I removed most of my other code that actually does useful things I need.
Basically, I decorate `MyUserString` using `__init_subclass__` in `Mixin` so that all methods in `MyUserString` and its base classes (I skipped `Mixin`) are decorated by `func_decorator`. During the decoration process, I follow MRO and skip the methods that have already been handled according to `handled_funcs` (i.e., handled_funcs has all the methods that should not been decorated, either because I don't want them to be decorated or because they have already been decorated, e.g., `__new__` which I add at the very beginning).

Now, the interesting thing I found is that if I add `__subclasshook__` in the set, I got the correct result, i.e.,
`isinstance([], UserString) == False`. But why? The `func_decorator` simply returns the same value as the original function, and more importantly, `UserString` is not even decorated by `class_decorator` (I think, because `setattr` always sets the attribute for `cls`, which is `MyUserString`, but perhaps I am wrong)?

I know `UserString` inherits from `ABC` and `ABC` somehow defines this `__subclasshook__` for `isinstance`...but I can't put two and two together! Can someone please explain what happened?