# How can I download Images by selenium?

Tags: python, image, selenium

```
cat_list = ['008']
book_num = list(range(20))
page_num = list(range(1,10))

b_title = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome('~')

for c in cat_list:
    url = 'http://www.yes24.com/24/Category/Display/001001016003'+ str(c) + '?ParamSortTp=04'

    for p in page_num:
        driver.get(url + '&PageNumber=' + str(p))
        time.sleep(1)

        for n in book_num:
            first_img = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('goods_imgSet')
            first_img[n].click()

            time.sleep(1)

            html = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

            book_pdate = soup.find('span', {'class': 'gd_date'})
            book_pyear = book_pdate.text

            if str(2020) in book_pyear:
                book_title = soup.find('h2', {'class': 'gd_name'})
                print(book_title.text)
                b_title.append(book_title.text)

                book_img = soup.find_all('em', {'class': 'imgBdr'})
                img_url = book_img[0].find('img')['src']
                img_url = img_url + '.jpg'
                print(img_url)
                urllib.request.urlretrieve((img_url, img_url.find('img')['src'] + "jpg"))
            else:
                break

            driver.back()
```

I tried to bring pictures of each book after accessing page url through the list.

I can bring image url but I have a problem saving the file.

The error is as follows ***TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object***

How can I save the image?

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813704/how-to-download-an-image-using-selenium-any-version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727583/re-sub-erroring-with-expected-string-or-bytes-like-object This link will help you to resolve this