# How to handle "expected string or bytes-like object" while removing non-alphabets from a pandas df column using regular expression?

Tags: python, pandas, python-re, dtype

**Context:**

I have a **df** like this:

| title | text |
| --- | --- |
| Donald Trump Sends Out $15B | Donald Trump just couldn't wish all Americans |
| Drunk Bragging Trump Staffer Started | House Intelligence Committee Chairman Devin |
| ... | ... |

Both `title` and `text` are of **object** datatype

I am trying to run the following code:

```
for i in range (0, len(msg)):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ', df['title'][i])
    review = review.lower()
    review = review.split()
    review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in stopwords.words('english')]
    review = ' '.join(review)
    corpus.append(review)
```

**Error:**

However, I am getting the following error on `re.sub` line:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727583/re-sub-erroring-with-expected-string-or-bytes-like-object). But no progress. I am still getting same error.

**Desired output:**

```
>code: corpus[0:1]
>Result: [['donald trump send    b'], ['drink brag trump staffer start']]
```

**What I tried?**

I tried all the possibilities from the above SO link. Also, tried changing the datatype of column by `df['title'] = df['title'].astype('string')`. Getting same error :(

**Additional info:**

- If I use different code to replace non-alphabets and try to run, I am getting `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'` error in `lower()` line
- I have a different df in different notebook. This code works perfect (object being datatype)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post the `expected output` based on your sample input?

Comment: `object` makes no sense at all here; how did you create them?

Comment: @MayankPorwal, Have added desired output. (changed input for better interpretation)

Comment: @tripleee, The dataset is available in kaggle and by default the dtype is `object`. I heard `object` refers to `string`

Comment: Can you try typecasting `df['title'][i]` to `str(df['title'][i])` inside `re.sub` statement?

Comment: @SandeepGusain, I tried this: `re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ', str(df['title'][i]))`.. but getting `KeyError: 23481`

Comment: @Arun, See if @SultanOrazbayev answer helps. Else try checking if `df['title'][i]` contains the value you want.

Comment: @SandeepGusain, It did not help and if I try to ignore `re.sub` step,  I am getting `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'` as mentioned in additional info

Answer (score 0):

One common reason for this error is that there is a `NaN` in the relevant column. A quick way to fix this is to assign an empty string to such values:

```py
df['title'] = df['title'].fillna("").astype('string')
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.  I ran this code and getting same error in `re.sub` line

Comment: Also, there are no `NaN` values as `df.isna().sum()` gave me `0`